# Matlab create wav file

Tags: matlab, audio

I have audio signal array. I need to create wav file.

```
Fs = 44100;                   % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 4096;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector

%real input signal
y = [-60, -95, -144, -100, -118, -106, -92, -15, 9, -63, -33, -16, -63, -21, -11, -72, -45, -33, 45, -42, -31, 46, -73, 70, 45, 42, 97, 11, 58, -10, -3, 26, 13, 65, -22, 12, -39, -96, -23, -53, 10, 14, 9, 27, -56, -33, 21, -19, -53, -72, -106, -92, -111, -72, -67, -69, -42, -72, -85, -161, -148, -100, -65, -8, -61, -59, -125, -112, -63, -114, -50, -73, -106, -104, -97, -64, -140, -90, -134, -207, -186, -206, -172, -224, -168, -211, -256, -194, -300, -221, -223, -261, -239, -287, -241, -254, -201, -206, -222, -158, -214, -216, -206, -228, -195, -212, -188, -206, -210, -211, -234, -197, -152, -200, -184, -186, -209, -178, -250, -238, -218, -223, -196, -248, -249, -278, -311, -291, -285, -243, -237, -252, -244, -243, -260, -327, -337, -321, -314, -341, -312, -337, -367, -358, -395, -367, -395, -406, -383, -402, -335, -375, -398, -400, -438, -383, -389, -429, -432, -395, -419, -401, -393, -384, -328, -375, -339, -345, -362, -341, -345, -333, -394, -315, -357, -377, -327, -377, -280, -335, -289, -281, -371, -273, -330, -282, -281, -234, -216, -289, -212, -292, -232, -249, -295, -238, -329, -264, -319, -311, -286, -299, -279, -309, -244, -261, -265, -289, -315, -317, -343, -258, -323, -333, -266, -326, -290, -321, -335, -275, -274, -325, -305, -236, -256, -273, -284, -319, -307, -267, -284, -283, -310, -335, -299, -295, -270, -198, -228, -248, -228, -234, -206, -235, -216, -164, -231, -184, -136, -182, -148, -174, -130, -88, -84, -45, -76, -11, -3, -23, 7, -46, 25, 0, -14, -6, -16, 52, -33, 21, 33, -12, 46, 9, 51, 33, 45, 33, -3, 71, 4, 88, 85, 84, 143, 75, 151, 59, 79, 128, 63, 190, 187, 182, 176, 145, 178, 99, 173, 204, 143, 133, 158, 183, 145, 194, 163, 197, 238, 172, 188, 241, 293, 287, 302, 300, 256, 278, 262, 291, 278, 246, 268, 260, 271, 270, 309, 274, 330, 341, 335, 308, 309, 391, 365, 363, 379, 347, 331, 325, 375, 357, 342, 349, 373, 414, 394, 419, 373, 366, 385, 398, 376, 405, 406, 305, 359, 335, 385, 361, 275, 242, 298, 436, 334, 438, 315, 325, 294, 295, 412, 227, 402, 319, 180, 368, 244, 397, 221, 300, 374, 232, 408, 138, 258, 276, 315, 473, 250, 372, 309, 254, 386, 285, 363, 322, 309, 309, 277, 341, 325, 323, 284, 333, 335, 303, 288, 265, 302, 291, 284, 254, 202, 224, 239, 222, 208, 256, 196, 172, 172, 132, 175, 106, 106, 126, 124, 191, 136, 132, 123, 150, 119, 69, 89, 45, 117, 182, 151, 178, 129, 146, 159, 137, 174, 178, 166, 129, 163, 180, 154, 174, 129, 125, 151, 108, 197, 181, 152, 250, 198, 165, 138, 124, 171, 137, 196, 177, 151, 184, 118, 188, 176, 154, 124, 109, 164, 108, 180, 136, 130, 184, 137, 199, 117, 138, 178, 150, 213, 159, 182, 134, 170, 218, 156, 229, 164, 204, 210, 204, 214, 104, 164, 124, 113, 122, 80, 91, 108, 130, 130, 91, 55, 82, 115, 89, 147, 114, 110, 71, 94, 114, 96, 148, 93, 141, 158, 162, 178, 84, 151, 120, 99, 148, 101, 152, 181, 198, 225, 231, 208, 128, 212, 232, 242, 240, 173, 203, 201, 206, 186, 166, 219, 225, 200, 211, 186, 184, 184, 172, 198, 151, 159, 127, 124, 186, 135, 205, 162, 174, 172, 123, 214, 135, 188, 176, 130, 188, 142, 204, 172, 169, 178, 200, 184, 70, 133, 82, 35, 69, 1, 31, 58, 89, 90, 60, 92, 112, 136, 162, 197, 180, 204, 215, 191, 192, 107, 123, 215, 189, 190, 235, 226, 261, 294, 220, 262, 269, 215, 263, 237, 250, 291, 218, 300, 250, 236, 282, 186, 198, 231, 314, 282, 259, 291, 216, 268, 282, 262, 282, 223, 280, 267, 248, 262, 265, 266, 230, 246, 217, 180, 151, 145, 173, 192, 217, 216, 157, 143, 111, 109, 164, 157, 175, 139, 125, 156, 84, 129, 136, 143, 133, 107, 149, 105, 154, 113, 93, 82, 17, 69, 33, 65, 45, 18, 40, -21, 40, 16, 42, 103, 80, 74, 38, 59, 21, 52, 51, 20, 43, 2, 33, 3, -10, -6, 2, 7, -10, 53, 7, 66, 82, 60, 80, 12, 44, -42, -64, -45, -42, -27, -95, -47, -129, -136, -106, -142, -118, -200, -145, -118, -144, -101, -117, -100, -157, -146, -116, -172, -122, -98, -95, -94, -104, -61, -78, -98, -37, -49, -75, -76, -38, -7, -66, 9, -9, -79, -53, -63, -33, -90, -69, -53, -112, -66, -133, -78, -71, -100, -54, -102, -60, -109, -93, -49, -70, -77, -71, -70, -27, -28, -45, -87, -56, -85, -112, -63, -49, -90, -84, -111, -167, -93, -118, -44, -81, -142, -27, -124, -54, -28, -63, -32, -193, -85, -67, -118, 36, -81, -37, -122, -98, -64, -161, -19, -93, -73, 8, -49, 10, -112, -45, 7, -21, 97, -20, 13, -32, 36, 89, 39, 80, 21, 33, 20, 19, 72, 82, 111, 98, 81, 106, 100, 126, 110, 87, 146, 99, 142, 220, 239, 269, 206, 184, 184, 182, 218, 181, 226, 221, 216, 192, 184, 214, 163, 222, 172, 170, 217, 217, 291, 203, 245, 190, 202, 229, 135, 200, 172, 238, 232, 184, 184, 181, 258, 162, 215, 192, 170, 186, 193, 269, 194, 260, 265, 233, 270, 228, 255, 239, 257, 255, 268, 270, 219, 291, 267, 289, 267, 250, 280, 257, 303, 262, 305, 267, 243, 295, 235, 301, 230, 258, 309, 241, 326, 226, 230, 234, 208, 260, 194, 237, 212, 225, 256, 218, 280, 245, 252, 282, 257, 240, 242, 233, 204, 218, 221, 159, 137, 162, 121, 154, 149, 110, 126, 84, 86, 81, 113, 69, 61, 95, 28, 93, 80, 83, 121, 21, 73, 65, 32, 84, 85, 79, 57, 85, 60, 66, 93, 87, 133, 124, 138, 147, 144, 159, 120, 99, 92, 110, 89, 70, 62, 79, 109, 57, 102, 81, 85, 115, 55, 115, 106, 118, 99, 94, 102, 68, 124, 71, 75, 59, 23, 93, 3, 56, 21, -33, 57, -37, 19, 17, 33, 27, -27, 38, -37, 15, -11, -42, -12, -82, -18, -78, -73, -16, -103, -50, -40, -19, 53, 3, -31, 6, 5, -34, -31, -66, -2, -37, -5, -26, -47, -69, -66, 11, -32, -22, -17, 3, 20, -25, 43, 25, -54, -37, -27, -48, -60, -17, -70, -7, -14, -67, -25, -126, -58, -13, -37, -5, -44, -60, -81, -81, -91, -89, -88, -73, -76, -110, -100, -131, -83, -89, -118, -89, -114, -80, -105, -61, -102, -112, -87, -146, -80, -124, -120, -91, -146, -118, -139, -93, -122, -93, -72, -146, -54, -130, -118, -73, -144, -46, -115, -69, -90, -133, -25, -66, -16, -48, -41, 3, -70, -35, -42, -35, -22, -22, 17, -2, 29, 23, -11, 17, 9, 50, 84, 37, 30, -4, 5, -1, -57, 14, -25, -75, -64, -40, -43, -81, -30, -37, -14, 9, -12, 31, 28, 11, 27, -15, 47, 17, -1, -19, -44, -15, -49, -63, -88, -50, -47, -96, -116, -91, -86, -121, -63, -128, -118, -62, -203, -206, -102, -122, -160, -152, -172, -163, -132, -196, -110, -127, -198, -107, -156, -121, -121, -40, -120, -142, -106, -184, -118, -111, -47, -132, -138, -69, -178, -136, -222, -212, -92, -221, -100, -195, -215, -126, -222, -159, -207, -107, -136, -216, -158, -253, -196, -218, -205, -177, -182, -226, -278, -230, -232, -227, -204, -162, -182, -244, -225, -240, -236, -198, -234, -279, -296, -254, -285, -238, -281, -311, -309, -341, -315, -339, -303, -319, -311, -327, -370, -323, -325, -299, -243, -241, -254, -343, -332, -249, -245, -220, -185, -277, -307, -277, -281, -314, -283, -192, -212, -196, -237, -248, -222, -327, -220, -313, -348, -298, -359, -216, -234, -184, -233, -331, -331, -392, -230, -263, -273, -229, -315, -242, -377, -286, -248, -398, -317, -394, -371, -350, -395, -349, -382, -352, -381, -391, -368, -434, -335, -403, -369, -363, -402, -331, -396, -352, -288, -385, -370, -370, -331, -290, -351, -248, -304, -281, -190, -275, -239, -266, -297, -244, -282, -231, -260, -218, -192, -206, -146, -231, -200, -221, -280, -174, -192, -176, -106, -164, -184, -146, -130, -146, -172, -210, -207, -156, -170, -134, -102, -88, -92, -115, -99, -168, -188, -148, -158, -120, -42, -59, -32, -38, -78, -65, -80, -68, -70, -20, -37, 23, 47, -29, 77, 15, -30, 37, 4, 118, 43, 159, 147, 57, 216, 97, 142, 174, 156, 136, 86, 225, 192, 210, 280, 249, 279, 234, 270, 229, 186, 238, 258, 278, 268, 288, 286, 293, 287, 302, 305, 276, 326, 353, 306, 308, 320, 287, 303, 358, 307, 277, 258, 278, 286, 236, 277, 274, 264, 292, 267, 250, 234, 225, 225, 231, 254, 221, 287, 246, 206, 312, 246, 238, 257, 272, 274, 273, 313, 279, 282, 350, 361, 333, 325, 330, 346, 315, 290, 300, 309, 298, 268, 345, 270, 271, 259, 194, 330, 264, 376, 372, 277, 397, 357, 385, 338, 375, 422, 372, 405, 335, 414, 384, 330, 441, 410, 439, 448, 434, 405, 410, 555, 462, 430, 445, 397, 411, 357, 405, 405, 393, 393, 333, 273, 303, 346, 306, 328, 345, 364, 301, 295, 292, 321, 381, 383, 389, 423, 406, 378, 323, 377, 451, 408, 476, 400, 440, 484, 490, 489, 420, 448, 409, 475, 391, 301, 377, 368, 447, 454, 428, 423, 383, 430, 365, 357, 365, 372, 377, 355, 422, 428, 387, 421, 393, 350, 368, 312, 321, 309, 313, 353, 296, 325, 264, 282, 270, 240, 312, 229, 283, 255, 257, 275, 163, 281, 191, 173, 212, 158, 251, 145, 214, 252, 200, 253, 196, 239, 210, 210, 182, 164, 178, 126, 178, 198, 208, 199, 202, 216, 144, 173, 180, 131, 162, 154, 136, 143, 116, 109, 112, 114, 145, 119, 90, 121, 114, 151, 140, 132, 157, 126, 172, 180, 182, 190, 203, 213, 184, 222, 187, 202, 229, 192, 238, 244, 232, 246, 276, 305, 272, 257, 296, 288, 260, 276, 308, 273, 225, 305, 260, 251, 320, 215, 252, 256, 268, 294, 241, 243, 202, 255, 248, 271, 315, 183, 223, 221, 175, 210, 90, 165, 47, 24, 103, -17, 165, 138, 168, 218, 81, 162, 68, 19, 102, 125, 146, 134, 109, 110, 164, 154, 156, 127, 69, 95, 50, 56, 111, 187, 219, 135, 108, 113, 108, 77, 139, 221, 197, 189, 101, 104, 162, 166, 167, 165, 136, 103, 159, 99, 183, 271, 165, 226, 177, 126, 136, 154, 193, 149, 132, 64, 83, 117, 116, 146, 121, 141, 76, 29, 80, 54, 98, 105, 78, 125, 114, 110, 112, 77, 120, 136, 108, 123, 175, 188, 150, 161, 154, 173, 204, 166, 192, 168, 176, 242, 184, 252, 203, 223, 262, 176, 243, 158, 194, 209, 198, 251, 133, 205, 174, 184, 200, 153, 209, 99, 122, 89, 66, 143, 94, 139, 108, 132, 91, 23, 118, 85, 101, 108, 67, 57, 56, 120, 115, 121, 161, 152, 109, 136, 152, 131, 179, 180, 179, 146, 136, 155, 132, 111, 45, 93, 57, 7, 114, 58, 74, 84, 74, 96, 18, 123, 18, 21, 168, 24, 54, 29, -41, 32, 61, 21, -12, 27, -8, -20, 41, 3, 43, 31, -30, -20, -66, -36, -26, -48, -19, -9, -9, -101, -68, 15, -64, 23, 31, -11, 65, 51, 57, 56, 88, 53, 119, 112, 23, 172, 89, 95, 165, 60, 126, 76, 48, 112, 68, 92, 35, 45, 29, 31, 1, -59, 29, -34, -17, 5, -38, -21, -60, -36, -61, -78, -50, -13, -5, -23, 13, 5, -4, -72, -59, -52, -64, 76, -19, -29, -75, -77, -43, -140, -23, -31, -46, -42, -39, -21, -71, -14, -60, -80, -61, -64, -46, -49, 25, 15, 1, 12, -43, -78, -67, -31, 15, 23, 6, 13, -1, -29, -23, 1, -8, -27, 16, -32, -9, 21, -102, -49, -62, -120, -125, -110, -98, -135, -15, -71, -90, -57, -101, -33, -71, -53, -87, -110, -67, -136, -75, -98, -72, -46, -105, -46, -94, -69, -53, -68, -39, -30, -42, -84, -76, -104, -50, -92, -107, -46, -138, -110, -75, -103, -152, -146, -88, -134, -96, -111, -84, -88, -77, -27, -116, -68, -100, -41, -51, -138, -6, -105, -76, -31, -80, -43, -122, -43, -65, -109, -68, -122, -39, -74, -63, -41, -142, -70, -105, -68, -18, -104, -89, -124, -69, -66, -59, -54, -127, -60, -42, -103, -116, -133, -124, -86, -87, -88, -118, -102, -84, -134, -128, -125, -142, -174, -194, -146, -140, -89, -156, -160, -128, -166, -104, -194, -109, -106, -141, -34, -131, -61, -87, -115, -68, -94, -88, -126, -71, -110, -84, -19, -119, -82, -132, -140, -118, -122, -104, -144, -120, -136, -54, -147, -214, -94, -126, -125, -84, -126, -181, -129, -85, -112, -166, -183, -249, -325, -238, -212, -197, -152, -200, -131, -241, -220, -293, -423, -215, -268, -229, -287, -295, -158, -307, -203, -224, -276, -215, -367, -247, -255, -237, -102, -184, -174, -170, -220, -243, -200, -150, -130, -98, -172, -216, -178, -218, -164, -110, -209, -174, -192, -191, -133, -180, -83, -120, -124, -116, -192, -154, -196, -165, -170, -182, -194, -206, -154, -222, -146, -196, -275, -180, -236, -183, -184, -254, -246, -265, -269, -297, -296, -308, -319, -315, -347, -328, -333, -341, -323, -327, -300, -309, -374, -294, -265, -347, -278, -296, -356, -321, -335, -287, -327, -328, -289, -366, -317, -331, -334, -338, -339, -297, -345, -279, -341, -337, -303, -411, -295, -349, -337, -274, -353, -293, -354, -342, -355, -369, -315, -351, -273, -323, -321, -280, -342, -309, -305, -290, -309, -341, -315, -331, -341, -318, -359, -389, -363, -331, -311, -352, -330, -317, -331, -315, -291, -257, -282, -220, -258, -298, -210, -221, -214, -223, -236, -247, -277, -231, -255, -219, -209, -245, -214, -220, -211, -222, -167, -130, -162, -164, -188, -195, -172, -135, -188, -208, -186, -205, -195, -236, -182, -196, -228, -198, -221, -226, -244, -168, -226, -251, -173, -247, -195, -216, -126, -110, -206, -71, -129, -94, -92, -98, -35, -121, -69, -109, -68, -101, -126, -41, -138, -56, -84, -106, -51, -103, -47, -64, -62, -33, -61, -35, -41, -51, -44, -47, -39, -12, 30, 34, 4, 66, 32, 19, 90, 86, 90, 51, 80, 79, 81, 165, 47, 25, 21, 55, 81, 38, 90, 55, 43, 71, 51, 51, 37, 49, 34, 21, 94, 120, 87, 104, 106, 144, 161, 109, 84, 86, 93, 120, 139, 130, 126, 107, 84, 43, 65, 89, 50, 45, 88, 67, -30, 31, 36, 9, 66, 33, 55, 16, 81, 126, 71, 179, 101, 122, 113, 134, 183, 64, 190, 96, 82, 139, 62, 162, 86, 98, 95, 68, 116, 32, 72, 82, 77, 56, 21, 59, 5, 57, 51, -33, 7, -13, -9, -4, -23, 37, 11, 2, 39, 10, 3, -3, 29, 27, -28, 1, 1, -35, -38, -52, -13, -78, -88, -17, -64, -64, -82, -78, -113, -132, -62, -99, -94, -90, -85, -98, -117, -74, -93, -49, -45, -25, -34, -67, -22, -37, -54, -87, -74, -144, -121, -54, -89, -63, -158, -125, -96, -140, -130, -74, -59, -92, -23, -95, -90, -24, -36, -4, -77, 4, -59, -78, 12, -75, 40, 29, -10, -68, -116, -26, -72, -7, -9, -37, -19, -89, -53, -76, -105, -53, -104, -103, -146, -226, -206, -180, -171, -169, -238, -201, -222, -272, -178, -192, -176, -164, -235, -220, -180, -171, -225, -262, -210, -281, -182, -179, -194, -7, -70, -41, 6, -78, -33, -150, -190, -69, -78, -57, -76, -72, -33, -126, -31, -21, -164, -44, -63, -146, -172, -92, 2, -86, -79, -104, -134, -125, -148, -61, -19, -7, -64, -114, -100, -63, -4, -3, -2, -50, -43, -56, -60, -10, 17, 45, -15, 11, -47, -107, -19, -124, -63, -33, -170, -71, -86, -52, -68, -33, -23, -128, -20, -74, -39, 34, -27, 18, 85, 74, 14, 72, 25, 0, 76, 16, 31, 43, 56, 51, 37, 108, 75, 58, 67, 84, 64, 92, 125, 118, 105, 87, 99, 58, 66, 70, 91, 100, 68, 100, 23, 43, 88, 96, 135, 95, 138, 102, 92, 112, 112, 123, 59, 123, 126, 103, 118, 80, 98, 90, 129, 83, 64, 140, 145, 102, 94, 113, 60, 76, 43, 7, 33, 3, 21, -30, -46, -42, -1, 5, -52, 45, -52, -48, 33, -55, 2, -56, 32, 4, -55, 77, -36, 42, 49, 35, 52, -4, 61, 4, 55, 29, 8, 66, -17, 64, 15, -40, 13, 25, 22, 5, 59, 27, -11, 41, 1, -33, -25, -39, -50, -31, -23, -54, -41, -42, -78, -35, -56, -117, -33, -43, -108, -42, -53, -84, -109, -101, -119, -150, -114, -172, -136, -134, -156, -102, -199, -182, -190, -257, -224, -277, -234, -228, -239, -235, -273, -255, -311, -310, -352, -329, -331, -373, -305, -356, -369, -360, -357, -380, -381, -357, -397, -375, -333, -333, -396, -317, -321, -371, -281, -395, -323, -409, -416, -307, -414, -349, -425, -363, -367, -418, -293, -418, -385, -338, -353, -383, -405, -291, -378, -359, -360, -354, -329, -383, -275, -295, -289, -295, -323, -325, -409, -301, -317, -355, -299, -339, -368, -388, -366, -386, -432, -446, -373, -427, -516, -442, -452, -462, -448, -448, -519, -498, -414, -474, -418, -450, -442, -439, -449, -345, -401, -335, -265, -335, -275, -295, -241, -206, -212, -190, -226, -229, -221, -194, -158, -176, -180, -204, -192, -199, -242, -210, -262, -164, -134, -244, -179, -170, -154, -94, -148, -77, -179, -153, -138, -202, -88, -154, -120, -136, -156, -90, -193, -85, -91, -78, 50, -76, -32, -65, -90, -12, -50, 36, -25, -36, -36, -89, -42, -59, -1, -52, -33, -1, -95, -33, -103, -81, -70, -100, 9, -69, -23, -5, -21, 3, 43, 63, -31, 24, 38, 72, 76, 91, 97, 99, 165, 143, 110, 106, 198, 144, 56, 160, 172, 196, 186, 225, 274, 209, 236, 193, 182, 191, 213, 259, 212, 266, 233, 232, 262, 206, 269, 150, 168, 255, 173, 150, 194, 157, 170, 188, 82, 119, 120, 149, 164, 160, 141, 176, 201, 140, 102, 145, 99, 45, 120, 99, 144, 277, 234, 239, 205, 123, 171, -3, 87, 204, 105, 218, 145, 245, 206, 196, 359, 166, 225, 175, 118, 184, 166, 323, 264, 266, 232, 250, 299, 224, 325, 347, 386, 376, 329, 293, 291, 345, 293, 306, 224, 214, 216, 234, 254, 208, 265, 139, 97, 124, 98, 128, 74, 56, 33, 52, 68, 48, 82, 62, 3, 60, 75, 16, 63, 41, 11, 99, 89, 77, 102, 110, 117, 92, 130, 105, 84, 127, 110, 124, 122, 100, 136, 136, 149, 182, 104, 125, 131, 111, 194, 200, 202, 173, 72, 52, 58, 112, 172, 168, 213, 188, 194, 154, 181, 208, 133, 214, 157, 161, 126, 90, 152, 93, 146, 79, 48, 87, 61, 97, 66, 93, 24, 33, 112, 74, 66, 58, 59, 78, 92, 98, 99, 70, 90, 72, 91, 54, 66, 113, 55, 64, 41, -1, 59, 53, 52, 107, 13, 80, 54, 10, 83, 42, 95, 6, 39, 86, 11, 91, 54, 104, 107, 86, 104, 28, 124, 78, 117, 162, 114, 177, 161, 202, 197, 205, 238, 236, 267, 242, 211, 225, 246, 226, 195, 170, 206, 141, 127, 129, 36, 101, 44, 27, 65, 40, 91, 20, 58, 39, 29, 77, 4, 86, 26, 16, 61, -5, 39, 9, 84, 65, 43, 78, 61, 150, 64, 120, 236, 130, 141, 165, 201, 151, 161, 198, 113, 172, 158, 139, 128, 141, 203, 120, 87, 96, 116, 31, 33, 88, 65, 86, 60, 97, 75, -8, 35, 4, 31, 55, 94, 47, 51, 79, 3, 53, -5, 5, 49, 39, 72, 76, 68, 63, 47, -17, 21, 42, -2, 19, 23, 24, 40, 35, 33, 4, -3, 53, -13, -15, 47, -11, 25, -15, 3, 55, 39, 56, 70, 72, 7, 41, 78, 17, 39, 5, 15, 85, 21, 28, 51, 37, 23, -25, 46, -4, -15, 23, -24, 7, -29, 26, -27, -80, 22, -107, -63, -36, -12, -48, -144, -57, -98, -91, -87, -134, -110, -93, -138, -124, -63, -107, -88, -89, -96, -73, -54, -34, -112, -69, -51, -112, -136, -138, -120, -198, -104, -168, -186, -72, -190, -106, -124, -156, -94, -78, -104, -107, -55, -208, -138, -78, -179, -91, -162, -143, -95, -164, -87, -122, -120, -98, -90, -126, -148, -43, -52, -25, -2, -62, -124, -100, -82, -45, -49, -114, -139, -96, -66, -167, -82, -42, -158, -79, -92, -120, -121, -65, -34, -160, -39, -59, -104, -53, -42, 53, 14, 30, -62, -89, -23, -56, 17, -47, 17, 53, -35, 2, -24, 19, -3, 27, 27, 41, -22, -31, 23, -39, 28, -19, -100, -81, -110, -72, -113, -124, -122, -245, -179, -214, -201, -82, -116, -61, -5, -120, -84, -134, -237, -78, -110, -130, -104, -120, -68, -94, -48, -81, -134, -62, -191, -156, -45, -49, 51, 13, -17, -38, -68, -62, -86, 11, 11, -17, 7, -95, -94, -39, -44, -33, -73, -87, -79, -91, -22, 5, -13, 3, 27, 37, -18, 68, 62, -1, 54, -25, -10, -56, -22, 15, -56, -9, -83, -71, -94, -83, 29, -76, -20, -3, -39, 18, -16, 1, -7, 48, -28, -99, -19, -40, -83, -122, -60, -61, -71, -42, -68, -71, -77, -3, -39, -110, 3, 45, 11, 11, 110, 83, 58, 80, 13, 27, 16, 93, 64, 56, 76, -11, 6, -71, -23, -33, -89, -29, -107, -66, -108, -98, -94, -180, -124, -200, -184, -172, -180, -152, -202, -172, -216, -190, -212, -223, -185, -245, -212, -244, -256, -221, -239, -267, -193, -239, -275, -229, -292, -276, -318, -305, -301, -334, -303, -323, -289, -335, -299, -298, -357, -283, -315, -307, -299, -297, -271, -299, -296, -293, -287, -333, -357, -257, -301, -317, -297, -331, -310, -285, -278, -322, -291, -241, -266, -285, -281, -278, -283, -253, -238, -255, -311, -303, -305, -369, -355, -431, -450, -436, -470, -408, -415, -403, -431, -426, -371, -405, -327, -331, -338, -297, -286, -259, -328, -261, -270, -335, -275, -357, -298, -268, -319, -256, -253, -268, -320, -305, -345, -367, -293, -338, -283, -270, -302, -310, -333, -262, -285, -277, -248, -299, -273, -284, -296, -279, -286, -281, -283, -284, -279, -299, -263, -256, -269, -196, -226, -178, -166, -143, -98, -184, -116, -146, -130, -97, -177, -94, -132, -118, -124, -154, -150, -182, -140, -252, -177, -148, -200, -132, -153, -123, -152, -146, -164, -168, -190, -217, -205, -267, -195, -225, -237, -227, -277, -246, -273, -170, -247, -230, -163, -226, -167, -216, -136, -209, -200, -119, -170, -116, -181, -150, -168, -156, -134, -201, -110, -146, -77, -32, -72, -6, -86, -74, -39, -56, -18, -61, -30, -18, -45, -36, -70, -61, -74, -72, -58, -35, -14, -7, 11, -41, -75, 19, 13, -11, 105, 87, 104, 131, 78, 112, 77, 81, 102, 98, 104, 73, 78, 54, 102, 97, 80, 109, 61, 146, 155, 132, 164, 98, 107, 100, 73, 91, 76, 91, 101, 103, 123, 149, 111, 146, 158, 138, 161, 181, 208, 160, 218, 210, 213, 315, 278, 222, 195, 269, 270, 238, 300, 262, 261, 252, 214, 249, 189, 236, 221, 122, 134, 164, 190, 93, 128, 137, 89, 136, 44, 73, 68, 81, 148, 85, 117, 106, 148, 174, 170, 196, 217, 143, 106, 171, 190, 196, 160, 153, 178, 169, 201, 95, 135, 118, 25, 124, 15, 127, 225, 190, 293, 256, 164, 149, 56, 165, 248, 241, 274, 240, 283, 302, 307, 394, 278, 294, 328, 183, 285, 297, 360, 365, 283, 336, 255, 236, 271, 326, 414, 383, 396, 363, 327, 328, 331, 331, 336, 282, 203, 273, 272, 270, 335, 363, 311, 321, 369, 258, 319, 314, 284, 337, 271, 310, 267, 303, 289, 236, 309, 180, 234, 256, 268, 283, 212, 295, 204, 240, 274, 273, 280, 196, 276, 174, 236, 359, 203, 228, 278, 289, 236, 230, 287, 178, 249, 241, 172, 159, 129, 231, 191, 144, 271, 246, 131, 182, 256, 236, 212, 218, 170, 147, 185, 165, 167, 219, 164, 179, 193, 183, 168, 167, 207, 160, 159, 117, 74, 129, 82, 119, 95, 46, 87, -2, 51, 77, 28, 82, 62, 53, 33, 29, 19, -11, 22, 22, 58, 50, 49, 139, 133, 64, 101, 57, 12, 52, 40, 91, 46, 87, 76, 78, 135, 65, 134, 112, 167, 157, 152, 241, 164, 239, 168, 227, 303, 148, 261, 236, 219, 218, 191, 152, 147, 236, 109, 169, 163, 70, 200, 98, 127, 161, 127, 187];
% plot signal
plot(t,y);
title('Input Signal')
xlabel('time (milliseconds)')

%create wav.
wavwrite(y,Fs,16,'audio.wav');
```

Now if i want read wav file. I do:

```
[y, Fs, nbits, opts] = wavread('audio.wav');
```

y contents only -1 or 1 like [-1 -1 -1 -1 ... 1  1 -1 ]
Where is the problem?

Comment: As `y` is double (default for Matlab) it should be in the range `-1.0 <= Y <  +1.0` for `wavwrite`, values beyond this are fixed to +1 or -1 this is why y contains -1 and 1s... However as your defining nbits as 16 I guess that y is supposed to be int16, so adding `y=int16(y);` after defining y but before running `wavwrite` might fix your problem.

Comment: Converted to answer, also +1 for reproducible code!

Answer (score 3):

As y is double (the default data-type for Matlab) the documentation for `wavwrite` states it should be in the range -1.0 <= Y <  +1.0.

Values beyond this are fixed to +1 or -1 and the warning *"Data clipped during write to file:audio.wav"* is given.

This is why y only contains -1 and 1s.

---

As your defining `nbits` as 16 I guess that y is supposed to be `int16` so adding

```
y=int16(y);
```

after defining y but before running wavwrite should fix your problem.

**note**: if y was not originally intended to be int16 (or in the range -32768 <= y <= +32767) then this may cause changes to pitch which rescaling could fix.

Answer (score 1):

because the input signal is contains floating-point data, you can change

```
wavwrite(y,Fs,16,'audio.wav');
```

to

```
wavwrite(y/max(abs(y)),Fs,16,'audio.wav');
```